# How to underline only specific line in DataGrid view using Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am developing desktop application using c# winforms , where i have data entry form. in that data entry fields i copy data from word having some text format like underline and bold and paste it to my textbox and save it . when i show entered / stored data in gridview it would not show text underline and bold. Exapmle

While pasting data from MS word to textbox, it look like below:

```
Date: 18-4-19 (underline + bold)
some text
some text
some text
some text
Date: 19-4-19 (underline + bold)
some text
some text
some text
some text
```

when i stored data and show it on gridview it display date without underline + bold like below

```
Date: 18-4-19 
some text
some text
some text
some text
Date: 19-4-19 
some text
some text
some text
some text
```

how could i achieve this to remain date in underline + bold in gridview

need your kind help.

Comment: Did my answer help you somehow? If not just write what's the problem with it so i can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a CellFormatting event like so:
The second if statement could be smthing different based on your needs:

I'm assuming that your DataGridView name is 'myDataGridView' and the column name where you want to apply your changes is 'columnName'

You can put that event subscription code (1st line) either in your constructor right after the pregenerated method 'InitializeComponent()' or Subscribe to that event via Visual Studio / Properties / Events.

```
    ..
    myDataGridView.CellFormatting += myDataGridView_CellFormatting;
    ..

    private void myDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
        // First ill check if im in right column
        // Second if checks if the value starts with "Date"
        if (e.ColumnIndex == myDataGridView.Columns("columnName").Index) {
            if (myDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("columnName").Value.ToString().StartsWith("Date")) {
                 // apply your formatting
                 myDataGridView.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
            }
        }
    }
```